# gwt4nb; running new project = blank page

Tags: gwt

I'm using gwt-2.4.0, netbeans 7.0.1, and I have GWT4NB installed.

I create a new project using "Java Web Application" project wizard, and I add the "Google Web Toolkit" framework when asked to add frameworks. The GWT installation folder is selected, and I choose a name for GWT Module etc etc etc.

After all that, I then debug the project, and get nothing but a blank page in my browser window. When I adjust the "title" tag in the "welcomeGWT.html" file and reload the page, that takes effect, but nothing in the EntryPoint class works...

I remember having this problem before (about 2 years ago when I started a previous project), and I thought I fixed that by adjusting something in one the configuration files, but I can't seem to track it down now.

So it's a brand new project, no code added or anything, and it does "run" but the GWT stuff doesn't work.  The "GWT Development Mode" window does appear, and I can click the "Launch Default Browser" button which does work, but again, only the "welcomeGWT.html" page loads. I don't see any logging tabs appear in the window either (like it does in my other GWT project).

Anybody have any ideas? I suspect it's just a configuration error... ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently gwt4nb doesn't support gwt 2.4 at this point; switching to gwt 2.0.2 which I also have installed works correctly.